# Llamada a procedimeinto almacenado

Tags: java, base-de-datos, oracle, prepared-statements

Buenos días estoy tratando de llamar un procedimiento almacenado en Oracle, pero al iniciar mi programa me aparece el siguiente error:

> Stacktrace:] con causa raíz java.sql.SQLException: Falta el parámetro IN o OUT en el índice:: 1

No se cual seria el error, no tengo mucha experiencia en llamar procedimientos almacenados, si me podrían ayudar, les quedaría agradecido.

```
<% String campus = "";
                try{

                    Linea del Error***coWF.prepareStatement("BANINST1.BZSKESPE.P_AULAS_DISPONIBLES_CAMPUS(:PAR_CAMPUS, '" + campus + "' )").executeQuery();****
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Error Procedimiento Almacenado:"+e);

                    ResultSet rsA = co.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT SZARPGN_CAMPVAR3 ||' - ' ||SZARPGN_CAMPVAR4 AS AULA,SZARPGN_CAMPVAR7 ||' - '  ||SZARPGN_CAMPVAR8 AS HORARIO,SZARPGN_CAMPVAR7 AS HORA_INICIO,SZARPGN_CAMPVAR8 AS HORA_FIN\n"
                            + "FROM SATURN.SZARPGN, SLBRDEF\n"
                            + "WHERE SZARPGN_IDREPORT = 'AULAS_'||:PAR_CAMPUS\n"
                            + "AND SLBRDEF_BLDG_CODE = SZARPGN_CAMPVAR3\n"
                            + "AND SLBRDEF_ROOM_NUMBER = SZARPGN_CAMPVAR4\n"
                            + "AND SLBRDEF_RMST_CODE = 'AC'\n"
                            + "AND SLBRDEF_ROOM_TYPE = 'C'\n"
                            + "AND SZARPGN_CAMPVAR9 IS NOT NULL\n"
                            + "ORDER BY 3,4,1").executeQuery();
                %>
```

Comment: El problema relacionado a el error que agregas es debido a que el query es incorrecto, en realidad no estas llamando un SP es un query pero este es incorrecto.

Comment: perdon puse mal el query me falto el CallLinea del Error***coWF.prepareStatement("CALL BANINST1.BZSKESPE.P_AULAS_DISPONIBLES_CAMPUS(:PAR_CAMPUS, '" + campus + "' )").executeQuery();****